# New AMD Ryzen build Ubuntu 18.04 complete freeze

Tags: ubuntu, amd

I am new Ubuntu. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LPS on newly built machine (specs below). The screen randomly keeps freezing (also when idle). The system is completely or partially irresponsive to keyboard/mouse, while the fans keep running and only reset/ turning off violently helps.

Since I am new to Ubuntu, I do not know where to start looking for the problem...

Machine:

AMD Ryzen 7 2700X

Gigabyte B450 Aorus Pro

MSI Armor Radeon RX 570

Corsair Vengeance Ram

Corsair CX550M PSU

Samsung 970 Evo

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683

Comment: Run memtest86 available on the media you installed Ubuntu from.  If this fails for any reason, you need to fix your hardware first.

Comment: @A.B thanks but since I am not an expert, I am a bit overwhelmed by the amount of information given at the links url. Could you help me out by being a bit more specific what  you think?

Comment: @user400359 there are years of messages. There's a possible bug on this CPU related to the CPU being idle and (hardware) power supply not behaving correctly with low power drawn when CPU is idle. The problem is more likely on the board rather than the CPU itself.  Most workarounds are about not letting the CPU too idle (including not letting the best "sleep" mode happen). There might also be BIOS patches related to power feed. As I don't have this hardware, I'm not going to go much further. You should read all the messages, even if it takes time. Also start by updating your BIOS to latest